# Deserialize json into model

Tags: c#, json

I have a json like this:

```
[  
   {  
      \"childNodes\":null,
      \"children\":null,
      \"key\":\"\",
      \"subKey\":{  
         \"buffer\":\"\",
         \"offset\":0,
         \"length\":0,
         \"value\":\"\",
         \"hasValue\":true
      },
      \"isContainerNode\":false,
      \"rawValue\":null,
      \"attemptedValue\":null,
      \"errors\":[  
         {  
            \"exception\":null,
            \"errorMessage\":\"Incorrect password.\"
         }
      ],
      \"validationState\":1
   }
]
```

So I want to deserialize it into model, so I create model like:

```
 public  class JsonDeserializeModel
    {

        public class SubKey
        {
            public string buffer { get; set; }
            public int offset { get; set; }
            public int length { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
            public bool hasValue { get; set; }
        }

        public class Error
        {
            public object exception { get; set; }
            public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public object childNodes { get; set; }
            public object children { get; set; }
            public string key { get; set; }
            public SubKey subKey { get; set; }
            public bool isContainerNode { get; set; }
            public object rawValue { get; set; }
            public object attemptedValue { get; set; }
            public List<Error> errors { get; set; }
            public int validationState { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Then I try to deserialize as:

```
  JsonDeserializeModel completeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDeserializeModel>(response.content);
```

But it throws exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Project.Models.JsonDeserializeModel' because the type requires a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

I didn't understand where the error is. Can someone knows or have more experience to know what is wrong? Regards

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to deserialize a json array into an object.
Also, you need to reference the nested object type RootObject.

try

```
JsonDeserializeModel completeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDeserializeModel.RootObject[]>(response.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess and totally untested, however you have nested classes (which seems suspect to say the least) Try this.

```
var completeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDeserializeModel.RootObject>(response.content);
```

or better, remove the class nesting

```
public class SubKey
{
    public string buffer { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public bool hasValue { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public object exception { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public object childNodes { get; set; }
    public object children { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public SubKey subKey { get; set; }
    public bool isContainerNode { get; set; }
    public object rawValue { get; set; }
    public object attemptedValue { get; set; }
    public List<Error> errors { get; set; }
    public int validationState { get; set; }
}

...

var completeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.content);
```